# Django - highcharts changes dot i comma

Tags: python, django, highcharts

I'm using highcharts in my app and I have a little problem.
I have a context (e.g. MyContext) like this:

```
[('September', 252.33333333333334), ('April', 100.3543)]
```

in template:

```
series: [{
            data: [
                {%for i, j in myContext%}
                ['{{i}}', {{j}}],
                {%endfor%}
            ]
        }]
```

But my context is 'converter(?)' to something like this:

```
['September', 252,333333333], ['April', 100,0],
```

And I get a comma instead a dot. So in my charts I can't see my 'full' number. I get only '252' in September instead '252.33333333'

Do you guys have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
[('September', 252.33333333333334), ('April', 100.3543)]
```

one way can be in the views:

```
def comma_format(value):
    left, right = str(value).split('.') # or replace
    return ','.join((left, right))


context = [('September',(comma_format(252.33333333333334))), ('April', comma_format(100.3543))]
```

in the template I do not know.

Answer (score 0):

set USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = False in settings.